# Why the amount of build files increased after installing ArcGIS JS in the Angular application

Tags: angular, build, arcgis, arcgis-js-api, esri-maps

I have installed the **@arcgis/core** by using npm into my Angular application.
After that when i'm going to deploy the changes in to my QA environment, it has more than **500 build files**. Earlier it was only 19 build files.

Can anyone help me to reduce the files and tell me why this happened.

npm package - https://www.npmjs.com/package/@arcgis/core

**ts.file**

```
import { Component, OnInit, ElementRef,Input,OnDestroy,ViewChild,} from '@angular/core';
import Map from "@arcgis/core/Map";
import config from '@arcgis/core/config';
import MapView from '@arcgis/core/views/MapView';
import FeatureLayer from '@arcgis/core/layers/FeatureLayer

    const map = new Map({
      basemap: 'topo-vector',
      layers: esriLayers
  });
  const view = new MapView({
      container,
      map: map,
    });

  this.view = view;
```

**.html file**

```
<!-- Map Div -->
<div #mapViewNode></div>
```

Comment: It looks like you have already installed `@arcgis/core` which is the recommended package to use when integrating ArcGIS API with Angular. `arcgis-js-api` and `@arcgis/core` provide the same logic, with the only difference between them being that `arcgis-js-api` is the AMD version of the API and `@arcgis/core` - the ES Modules one. You only need `@arcgis/core`. Is there a reason you have also installed `arcgis-js-api`?

Comment: Hi @ardentia. Could you please tell me how did you recognized that I've installed both? We are getting @arcgis/core after installing arcgis-js-api? isn't it? I'm confused a little bit there that's why :)

Comment: My assumption was based on your imports - I saw `@arcgis/core`. I actually haven't used `arcgis-js-api` because I assumed it provides an AMD version of the modules.

Comment: I have a similar issue. It seems to build countless locales (translations) for arcgis components. The problem: I didn't yet find a to only build what I really need.

Comment: Hi @ardentia. Sorry it was a mistake. I didn't use arcgis-js-api. Just @arcgis/core. But still having the same issue.

Comment: Hi @sandrooco. I also feel the same. When I run ng serve, it's generating bunch of js files at the moment.

Comment: It's not the best library so far but they are going into the right direction. I just added the arcgis-js-api tag so esri might find it and answer.

Comment: @KalanaTebel we asked some questions over at the duplicate posting on Esri Community: https://community.esri.com/t5/arcgis-api-for-javascript-questions/why-the-amount-of-build-files-increased-after/m-p/1135353#M76012. In general, unless you have a large application with a bunch of dynamic imports you shouldn't have that many modules. Keep in mind, the initial load of the application typically only uses a small portion of the on-disk modules, the remaining modules are lazy loaded dependencies. Please provide an example github repo so we can examine this issue further.

Comment: @AndyGup. As you can see in the above code snippet, they way I'm importing is different from the way I used to import libraries in other components. (No curly brackets after import keyword) . I feel like something happening there. Will it be a issue?